# BQL Delegate error when trying to GET Default Customer/ShippingContact data via REST

Tags: rest, acumatica

I am trying to pull information from Acumatica's default endpoint using REST and when I try to get the Customer/ShippingContact data, I get the following errors:

```
Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:
ShippingContact.ContactID: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.DisplayName: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Email: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Fax: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.FirstName: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.JobTitle: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.LastName: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.MiddleName: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Phone1: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Phone1Type: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Phone2: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Phone2Type: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.Title: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
ShippingContact.WebSite: View DefLocationContact has BQL delegate
```

The GET request is being made with following URL:

```
http://192.168.1.78/a000/entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer?$expand=ShippingContact
```

Are there any specific tricks to getting something like this to work via REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the Acumatica ERP version 2018r1 Update 11. As a temporary workaround you can build a generic inquiry to read this data. 
Another approach you may use is to retrieve customer data by specifying the customer you want this data for. 
Like that:

```
http://host/site/entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer/ABARTENDE?$expand=ShippingContact
```

Comment: Thank you for the info, I will apply the update.  Do you know if this applies to getting something like the Balance for a customer?  When I try to get it, I get the same BQL delegate error message.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the query? By the way, I've just updated an answer with another 'workaround'

Comment: It doesn't look like the Customer Summary -> Balance is a part of the Default contract, so I was extending the existing Customer endpoint to include it.  I get the same BQL delegate error message when trying to add a field that pulls in that value.

Comment: I am now trying to pull down contacts and get the same BQL delegate error when trying to get the Address portion of the Contact endpoint via `http://host/site/entity/Default/17.200.001/Contact?$expand=Address`.

Comment: The basic rule here is like that: Get List requests works only with optimized entities. Unfortunately, the detail entities are usually non optimized. To select the entity with its non optimized detail you should use Get request that will return only one record, not the list of records. To perform Get Request, you should use key field values, like customer CD in my answer above.

Comment: @dmitrii-naumov What does "optimized entities" mean it that context? What do you need to do so that an entity is "optimized"?